# Add a class to each element that has text on its title attribute

Tags: php, jquery

I'm generating content for the title attribute dynamically:

```
<div class="point_data">
<a href="#" title="<?php the_sub_field('points_description'); ?>"></a>
```

How to add the class `.point-tooltip` to each anchor link inside the `.points_data` div that has text on its title attribute (in other words, which is not empty)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this:

```
$('.point_data a[title]').addClass('point-tooltip');
```

If the title can be empty use this:

```
$('.point_data a[title][title!=""]').addClass('point-tooltip');
```

[`attribute-not-equal-selector`](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-not-equal-selector/):

> Description: Select elements that either don't have the specified attribute, or do have the specified attribute but not with a certain value.

Comment: This does not solve the solution to add a class to the anchors.

Comment: @ErikPhilips. added that bit.

Comment: Is this `if the title can be empty use this` is `[title!=""]` correct, wouldn't that mean if the title is not empty??

Comment: @ErikPhilips. I meant if there an option for the title attribute to exist what with no value like `<a title="">` or `<a title>`. is it clear now?

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".point_data a[title][title!='']").addClass("point-tooltip");
```

Comment: This would add the class to the `A` not the `Div`

Comment: "How to add the class .point-tooltip to each anchor link inside the .points_data"

Comment: You're right, I read it wrong.  But should remove `[title]` as OP states *title attribute (in other words, which is not empty)?*.

Comment: This will add the class to `<a> </a>` as well. _"Description: Select elements that **either don't have the specified attribute**, or do have the specified attribute but not with a certain value."_ [source](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-not-equal-selector/)

Answer (score 0):

Try with this...

```
 $(".point_data").find("a[title]").each(function(){
    var titleval = $(this).attr("title").trim();
    if(titleval.length != 0)
    {
        $(this).attr("class","point-tooltip");
    }
});
```

See this JSFiddle Link:
http://jsfiddle.net/rfb23/1/

Comment: You should use `addClass` instead of `attr` and it can be done with one simple selector. [read this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10292594/601179).

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to do this in PHP :

```
<div class="point_data">
<?php 
$title = the_sub_field('points_description');
if(empty($title)) { ?>
  <a href="#" >BLAA</a>
<?php }
else { ?>
  <a href="#" class="point-tooltip" title="<?php echo $title ?>">BLAA</a>
<?php } ?>
```